# Iterate over JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, json.net

I've read several examples of how to do what I want but none seem to work. I want to iterate over a JSON array but it's not working for me. When I look in chromes js console my data looks like this:

```
"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"EntryId\": 3,\r\n    \"Title\": \"Tiny Living For sales\",\r\n    \"Description\": \"This is a house for sale\",\r\n    \"AddressViewModel\": {\r\n      \"AddressId\": 3,\r\n      \"Street1\": null,\r\n      \"Street2\": null,\r\n      \"City\": \"Los Angeles\",\r\n      \"LocationId\": 5,\r\n      \"LocationName\": \"California\",\r\n      \"PostalCode\": null,\r\n      \"Phone\": null,\r\n      \"Latitude\": 34.052234,\r\n      \"Longitude\": -118.243685\r\n    },\r\n    \"EntryCategoryName\": \"Houses for Sale\",\r\n    \"EventStartDate\": null,\r\n    \"EventEndDate\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"EntryId\": 2,\r\n    \"Title\": \"Tiny Living Workshop\",\r\n    \"Description\": \"This is a workshop\",\r\n    ...
```

And if I turn it into an object by doing so:

```
var myObject = eval('(' + locations + ')');
```

It looks like this (formated):

```
[
{
"EntryId": 3,
"Title": "Tiny Living For sales",
"Description": "This is a house for sale",
"AddressViewModel": {
  "AddressId": 3,
  "Street1": null,
  "Street2": null,
  "City": "Los Angeles",
  "LocationId": 5,
  "LocationName": "California",
  "PostalCode": null,
  "Phone": null,
  "Latitude": 34.052234,
  "Longitude": -118.243685
},
"EntryCategoryName": "Houses for Sale",
"EventStartDate": null,
"EventEndDate": null
},
{
"EntryId": 2,
"Title": "Tiny Living Workshop",
```

...

But when I try to iterate over it (either the raw JSON or the object) it gives me each letter of the JSON, not each object in the array

```
for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) { console.log(myObject[i]); }
```

Like so:

```
 "
 [
 \
 r
 \
```

Thanks

Comment: Not the problem, but don't use `eval()`, use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn `JSON.parse` is not available everywhere, your comment needs a disclaimer

Comment: JSON.parse() gives me the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was returning the JSON from my controller like this

```
return Json( jsonResults, "text/html");
```

I had to do this on a different controller to prevent IE from prompting the user to save the JSON results.
Anyways, that was putting quotes around the data so it wasn't being parsed correctly.

So I am now returning:

```
return Json( jsonResults);
```

Hopefully I don't have the IE problem (tested in 9 and didn't see it)

Answer (score 4):

You evaluate the JSON and assign the result to "myObject", and then you attempt to iterate through "locations". It's no wonder that that doesn't work :-)

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
   console.log(myObject [i]);
}`

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch that. The op is iterating through the source variable and not the converted variable.  Removing downvote and replacing with a nice shiny upvote ;)

Comment: The iterating example that I posted was on the raw JSON but I said that I get the same results when I iterate over the raw JSON or the Object.

Comment: @Dandotnet - I pasted the code from your question [into JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bSguR/) and it works fine.